# argument of method @selector

Tags: ios, methods, arguments, selector

I have a method @selector with parameter of type NSString. when I compile the app I get this error

```
No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:
withObject:forControlEvents
```

The method is declared in header file.
This is the code:

```
 -(void)loadDetailListViewController: (NSString *)nameTable{
      //......
  }

 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id 
  <MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
        //.....

   UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

   [rightButton addTarget:self action: @selector(loadDetailListViewController:) 
     withObject:self.nameTable forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //here the error


        //.....
   }
```

I don't know if the parenthesis are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that method does not exist. This does

```
[rightButton addTarget:self action: @selector(loadDetailListViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If you need to pass a string to the method, I would suggest subclassing UIButton with a string property and you can set it there. The button is passed as a parameter in your selector so you can get it and the string from there:

```
- (void)loadDetailListViewController:(MyCustomButtonClass *)button {

    // access the string from the button

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such signature for UIButton (UIControl) like the one you use.
Remove `withObject` and it will be fine. You may consider removing `tableName` argument since it's the object property and can be read directly.

Doc:

> - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 -(void)loadDetailListViewController: (id)sender{
      //......
  }

 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id 
  <MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
        //.....

   UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

   [rightButton addTarget:self action: @selector(loadDetailListViewController:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //here the error


        //.....
   }
```

Comment: The code you posted is incorrect. The `loadDetailListViewController:` method can't have a parameter of `NSString *`. If it has a parameter, it will be the sender of the action. In this case the button. So it should be `-(void)loadDetailListViewController:(UIButton *)button {`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating the compiler cannot find a method named `'addTarget:action:
withObject:forControlEvents` which can be called on the `UIButton`.

`UIControl` has a method of `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`, but not one containing "**withObject:**"

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method addTarget:action:  **withObject:** forControlEvents

Use:

```
[rightButton addTarget:self action: @selector(loadDetailListViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You don't need to pass self.nameTable to this method, you can access it inside loadDetailListViewController: just fine

Answer (score 0):

There is no method like : `addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action withObject:(id) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents`

change that to: `addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents`

Please refer : [UIControl Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)